# Usage of "method"

Tags: expressions

Which of these sentences is better?

> - The **method to** measure the intelligence of a man is to...
> - The **method for** estimating the intelligence of a man is to...

Is it *method to* or *method for*?

Comment: Why use *method*?  "The *way* to measure ..." is much more natural.

Comment: To measure != to estimate. Which do you intend as the meaning?

Comment: This is not a question about *method*. It's a question of preposition choice.

Comment: The prepositions *of*, *to* and *for* are all used with *method* with different meanings in appropriate contexts. There is at least one related/similar question asked on these pages earlier.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=method+of+measuring%2Cmethod+to+measure%2Cmethod+for+measuring&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmethod%20of%20measuring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmethod%20to%20measure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmethod%20for%20measuring%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any concrete rules, but "method of" or "method for" would seem more natural to me and are the usual constructions I see.

The only time I can recall "method to" being used is in "method to (his or her) madness," where method is to mean "purpose" more than "process."

Sources:

- The five APA style papers on my desk that all have a Methodology section and use one of the above phrasings. For what it's worth, "Method of" was used eight times, "method for" two times, and "method to" zero times.
- In the physical sciences and mathematics, methods are typically named as "Method of *_*_." E.g., Method of Exhaustion, Method of Images, Method of Coordination, Method of Infinite Descent, Method of Successive Frames.

Comment: @showtime Noooooo problem. If this is your accepted answer, would you mind clicking that checkmark next to it?

Comment: Why there's even a "method to madness" you see.

Answer (score -2):

the word'to' indicates intention / purpose.

When we say, 
Students study to gain knowledge.
We are making parallel two entities which are parallel
i.e. (noun + verb) before 'to' and (noun+verb) after 'to'
*We mean that 'studying' is done for the purpose of gaining knowledge.*

But when we say 'The method to measure the intelligence.....'
we are trying to make parallel two non-parallel entities.
i.e 'method' (a noun) is being made parallel to 'measure' (a verb)....... this is neither good and nor preferable.

Comment: What do you mean by "making parallel?"

Comment: Ramesh, can you explain where this "parallel entities" analysis comes from? It doesn't seem to have any basis in English grammar. -1